# Can I take arguments in Java in code runtime?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am writing a code using HTMLUnit to login into a user's **gmail** account. First of all, user will enter his emailId and password as arguments which will be used to login into his account. But supposedly, user's account has 2-step authentication enabled, and therefore after submitting login credentials, code will be redirected to a screen where user will have to enter the pin he will receive.

So I am thinking, if the code encounters such a scenario, it should pause the execution and ask the user to enter the pin that he received and after user enters the pin and presses enter, the code should resume executing and complete the login.

So, is this possible? Can a java program pause in between and take argument in runtime? If yes, how to do that? If no, can you suggest me an alternative solution?
Please help me, I really am stuck at this one.

Edit 1: I will run the code from command prompt, so is there a way to enter the pin in cmd instead of a dialogue box?

Comment: You can take input whenever you want.

Comment: @DaveNewton How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can eiter read System.in or display modal dialog in Swing(maybe not recommended):

```
String pin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your pin:", "Pin prompt",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
System.out.println(pin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OAuth for authentication. Here's the documentation url - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2